# Using formatters to make string from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a string from a dataframe. I want it to respect `formatters`, but I don't want headers in the string. How can I get both of these things: no header, yes formatting?

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'c': 1, 'd': 2.3}, index=[0], )
formats = {'c': '{: 10d}', 'd': '{: 2.5f}'}
formatters = {k: v.format for k, v in formats.items()}
df.to_string(formatters=formatters, index=False, header=True)

u'c        d\n        1  2.30000'


df.to_string(formatters=formatters, index=False, header=False)

'1  2.30000'
```

I believe the expected result is something like this?:

```
'         1  2.30000'
```

Comment: Headers meaning? You don't want the `1 ` to be printed along?

Comment: It seems to be only the leading empty characters that are removed. If filling with e.g. `0` it works, and also, the correct fractional part is retained. I also tried with multiple rows and it is only the first row that is affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I have never heard of `DataFrame`]

This just looks like a bug in `DataFrame` to me. Try reporting a bug to the developers.

As a workaround, it looks like you could just cut the first line off the string:

```
raw = df.to_string(formatters=formatters, index=False, header=True)
without_headers = '\n'.join(foo.splitlines()[1:])
```

Comment: Uh, no? My code removes the first line, not the first character.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a second `DataFrame` with everything formatted correctly

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for col_name, col in df.iteritems():
    df2[col_name] = col.apply(lambda x: formats[col_name].format(x))
```

and then concatenate everything together

> print(''.join(''.join(i[1:]) for i in df2.itertuples()))

```
'           1   2.30000'
```